# Trouble getting two jquery animations to happen at the same time

Tags: jquery, animation

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/abbeynormal/tugyj69h/

When I comment out line 5 of the jquery, the first animation runs fine.  When I add line 5 back in, nothing happens.

According to the answers I've seen here on SO, these two animations should occur at the same time, with or without the "queue:false" parameter.

Any thoughts on why this happens?  Thanks!

```
<!doctype HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
#container
{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    border-style: dotted;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#gameStage
{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: brown;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
#nextStage
{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="gameStage"></div>
    <div id="nextStage"></div>
</div>
<button id="animate">Animate</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script>
$("#animate").click(move)
function move()
{
    $("#gameStage").animate({left:"-100%"}, {duration:2000, queue: false});
//  $("#nextStage").animate({left:"50%"}), {duration:2000, queue: false});
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second line has a syntax error, note below how you close it

```
$("#nextStage").animate({left:"50%"}), {duration:2000, queue: false});
//                                  ^ here, syntax error !
```

replace it with

```
$("#nextStage").animate({left:"50%"}, {duration:2000, queue: false});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/tugyj69h/2/)